# Data inserted into Firebase using Android is not Visible

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying from too long to Insert data into Firebase

**Checked my Code weather am creating some error or what**

```
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mIncomeDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mExpenseDatabase;
```

**Inside method**

```
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser mUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid=mUser.getUid();

        mIncomeDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IncomeData").child(uid);
        mExpenseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ExpenseDatabase").child(uid);
```

**This is my code where am inserting Data**

```
                String id=mExpenseDatabase.push().getKey();
                String mDate=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

                Data data=new Data(inamount,tmtype,tmnote,id,mDate);
                mExpenseDatabase.child(id).setValue(data);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot and so I don't want your time to get wasted if you are getting the same problem.

**There is field called Rules in Firebase**
there you need to add **read , write permmissions **
and check weather those are given this has solved my problem as by default these are **false**

**.write should be True** so user will be able to write into Database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
   ".write": true
  }
}
```

**Hope This would be Helpfull**

[image]

Comment: FYI this would have been easier to discover if you checked the call to setValue for errors.  It would have given you a "permission denied" error.  This is very common.